# Blur an Image on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, writeablebitmapex

I'm using WriteableBitmapEX library trying to blur a Bitmap image at windows phone 8 I tried this code

```
Uri uri = new Uri(AnyUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
BitmapImage img1 = new BitmapImage();
img1.UriSource = uri;
img1.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap(img1);
var wbm2 = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(wbm, WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
PanoramaBackground.ImageSource = wbm2;
```

But there is an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
at the line `WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap(img1);`

Why this doesn't work ??

Comment: Are you sure this is a complete code sample? That code seems fine.

Comment: Yes, am sure that! and it doesn't work ! @DanielKelley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.New(0, 0).FromContent("RelativePathHere.png");
var blurredBitmap = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(bitmap, WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
ImageControl.Source = blurredBitmap;
```

**EDIT**

OK so it looks like you are getting the image from the web and you are having an exception because the image is not loaded yet. You need to subscribe to the ImageOpened event handler. Here is the code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("AbsoluteUriPath.png", UriKind.Absolute);
BitmapImage img1 = new BitmapImage(uri);
img1.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
img1.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
{
      WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(img1);
      var blurredBitmap = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(bitmap,
                WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);
            ImageControl.Source = blurredBitmap;
};
```

Comment: What if the image is not a relative one ?? the image source is absolute link from API

Comment: @HeshamHaleem I tried using your code and it also works. Can you share the absolute link that you are testing with?